# Difference Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop in network support

Tags: 14.04, server, lts

I installed a `Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS` on my laptop. Before I had a normal `Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS` running. Anything worked pretty good.

Now starting up my machine the network drivers are not working for both, ethernet and wlan.

According to the [ServerFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F) one of the differences between `Ubuntu Server` and `Ubuntu Desktop` are missing desktop packages. So since Desktop was working, I expected the Server to run on my machine the same way (without gui of course).

So my question is: If the missing desktop package (i.e. `ubuntu-desktop`) really is the main difference between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server, does it include any additional network drivers then or why does `Ubuntu Desktop` work with my laptop and `Ubuntu Server` does not?

Comment: What shows ifconfig -a? if you see interfaces like eth0/wlan0 it is all ok. you need only manual configuration of interfaces.

Comment: It shows my cards actually. `lshw` shows them inactive. But why is Ubtuntu Desktop capable of configuring the cards while Ubuntu Server is not?

Comment: Different use-cases for server and laptop/desktop. Usually server networking is one time configured and works all time. Laptop can be connected to home network/work network/other network.

Comment: what is the content of /etc/network /interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments and some research I found an answer for my question.

`Ubuntu Desktop` comes with [Network Manager](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Networkmanager) while `Ubuntu Server` configures its interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In my special case the setup in this file was incorrect which caused the problem. In case of `Ubuntu Desktop` the `Network Manager` was able to automatically configure my interface.

Last thing to mention is that it is quite easy to install `Network Manager` also on `Ubuntu Server`. I used this [documentation](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/NetworkManager/NetworkManager_ohne_GUI) which comes unfortunately only in German.